# Unable to locate command maven in project with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, configuration

I'm trying to setup a simple java rest service with spring boot and maven and I've downloaded maven and have my pom.xml located in the same folder as src so it's 
src & pom.xml -> main -> java -> hello

when I'm inside the hello folder and try to run maven clean package to build my jar file it says command maven not found.

I'm still relatively new to java web dev so making sure everything is configured correctly is difficult for me. I've downloaded maven but do I need to have the actual maven files in my project?

Any help is truly appreciated.

-Adam

UPDATE:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.124s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 04 11:47:08 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/89M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this      directory (/Users/adam419/Desktop/Programming/Java/dd-servlet/src). Please verify you invoked   Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Edit:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/adam419/Desktop/Programming/Java/dd-servlet/src/main/java/hello/GreetingController.java:[3,7] error: class Greeting is public, should be declared in a file named Greeting.java
[ERROR] /Users/adam419/Desktop/Programming/Java/dd-  servlet/src/main/java/hello/Greeting.java:[3,7] error: duplicate class: hello.Greeting
[INFO] 2 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

The pom.xml must be in the "root" folder.

```
/yourApp:
   - pom.xml
   - /src
        - /main/java
           ...
        - /test/java 
           ...
```

Comment: That is where it's located. Which directory should I invoke mvn from, such as when I execute mvn clean install?

Comment: In the dir where the pom is located

Answer (score 0):

Although you are making the mistake @Ralph has given in his answer, I don't think this mistake would give the error message you're getting.  To me it sounds like you haven't installed maven correctly.  [The install steps are at the bottom of this page](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).  Make sure you've followed the directions correctly.

The error you've added on says there's no pom at the directory you ran the command from.  You need to run the command in the same directory that the "pom.xml" file is in.

Comment: I was just writing maven instead of mvn, after I executed mvn I got an error message which I will update my original question with:

Comment: @AdamBronfin: That would explain it.

Comment: Forgetting anything I've set up now, can anyone please explain what I need to do to allow this rest server to successfully deploy?

Comment: And also, which folder I should always be invoking maven from when building/deploying the service

Comment: @AdamBronfin short answer: the directory with the pom.xml.  long answer: it depends on what the pom does and what you're trying to do with maven.

Comment: All this is for, is to have a rest server that can receive http requests from a ruby/sinatra app, then process this data, and send back json to that ruby/sinatra app. In principle I understand how to do this but you would be my savior if you could give me a practical course of action to achieving this.

Comment: @AdamBronfin You should read some tutorials on [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) and [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) .  I can't quickly teach someone how to do this from start to finish.

Comment: Probably the single most helpful thing you could tell me is simply what technologies to focus on and use. Because in my research efforts I've been bombarded by an array of options including spring, spring boot, using tomcat (which I've been using), to jetty, and jersey.

Comment: @AdamBronfin Jersey is what you need to allow RESTful web services in a java app.  But it's not stand alone.  It needs to run on a webapp container.  Jetty is a webapp container.

Comment: So now, everything seems to be compiling correctly but I'm having duplicated classes issues, I'll update my question with the logs

Comment: The file is clearly Greeting.java, along with Application.java and GreetingController.java

Comment: Yeah I catch your drift :/. I'm just bombarding the world with questions after reading tons of tutorials that always seem to miss or skip over something.

Comment: In all consolation, I discovered the root of the problem was my settings.xml file which contained references to a specific project or subset of project capabilities related to an organization I work at. The intention of this project is completely unrelated.